# TFS 2010 Backup and restoration proceedure

Tags: tfs

Following are the scenario in my environment

I have a tfs 2010 server which is running fine and i have schedule the backup for WSS_AdminContent,WSS_Config, Tfs_Warehouse,Tfs_Configuration. and one project which is created in tfs. Now i want to restore this TFS 2010 in my test environment.

I am in need of how do i proceed for the same and how can i restore my production environment in test environment.SO that if my production server is down i will be able to restore all projects in TFS 2010.

Thanks and Regards
Avinash Udawant
System Admin.

Answer (score 2):

You'll also need to backup other databases, including project collection databases and more.  Follow the MSDN guidance in order to make sure you get all the steps right for [backing up](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms253070.aspx) and [restoring](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252516.aspx) TFS.